# Mute other applications' sound when my application is playing a sound

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I would like to mute other applications sounds when my application is playing a sound. I know that this is possible in Windows 7 because it allows sound control on a per-application basis.

The specific scenario is my app needs to have its sound play exclusively; if other applications (eg Winamp, Media Player Classic etc) are playing a sound, they should be muted for the duration of the sound played by my application.

I would like to know how it can be done using Delphi? Which library/system call?

Comment: [What if two programs did this?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx)

Comment: Your assumption isn't necessarily valid. Just because the OS grants *users* the ability to control program's volume levels independently doesn't mean the OS grants programs the ability to control *other programs'* volume levels. It could be like shell-notification icons: Users can control which icons are kept visible, but programs don't get to say which icons are visible. (They can't even control their *own* visibility anymore.) I don't think this is your problem to solve. If the user thinks other programs are interfering with your program's audio, let the user deal with it.

Comment: I seriously hope that Windows 2020 will allow me to choose what apps can and cannot do. I appreciate that there are use cases for this, but this kind of behaviour should be forbidden unless I explicitly allow an application to do something like this.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this is easily achieved.

What if the other apps took the same view? Suppose another app decided that it wanted its sound to play and mute all other apps. Which app would win?

Comment: @Raym... @David: Agreed. Possibly, however, the OP could utilize the [ducking experience](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316773(VS.85).aspx) in Windows 7.

Comment: is right, I dont think there is a way for you to override and take control of the sound card to use solely for your own Application. I have never come across an Application that does this, in fact 3D Applications such as DirectX games even cannot do this.

Comment: @Andreas: Interesting! Thanks.

Comment: @Andreas: why don't you post your comments as a separate answer? It's quite a brilliant suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

On Vista & above you can do this by using CoreAudio/WASAPI & an [exclusive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) mode stream.

Answer (score 0):

[Mumble](http://mumble.sf.net) is doing this, you can look at source code.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look and get back.

Comment: I tried browsing the Git repository for Mumble in an attempt to find the source file that might have something to do with sound system manipulation but could not find one. If you know which file it is could you post a snippet here? Thx.

Comment: No, sorry. I just know that Mumble does that, but I never look at their source code.